# Height of tableview not completely increasing as per number of cells

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a tableview in my xib like so...

[image]

Now what I want to achieve is I want to increase the height of my tableview according to the number of cells I add in the tableview.

To achieve this, this is the code I have added..

In `viewDidLoad`..

`self.tableview.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: [], context: nil)`

And then added this function...

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    var frame = self.tableview.frame
    frame.size = self.tableview.contentSize
    self.tableview.frame = frame
  }
```

Also, I have 5 cells in my tableview.

Now if I run the app, I get the tableviewcells like so..

The top portion:-

[image]

And the bottom portion:

[image]

Here the top portion is overlapping some of the label content above and the last cell is also not leaving enough space at the bottom and it is getting clipped...

How can I fix this..?

**EDIT 1: After assigning the tableviewheight constraint**

[image]

Comment: Handle it with `tableViewHeightConstraint` instead.

Comment: could u maybe suggest how @PGDev..?

Answer (score 0):

Create an `outlet` for `tableView's` `height constraint`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Update it with the `tableView's` `contentSize` in `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`

```
func updateTableiewConstraints() {
    let height = self.tableView.contentSize.height
    self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = height
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    self.updateTableiewConstraints()
}
```

**`Constraints` for `tableView`:**

[image]

Comment: I tried what you suggested @PGDev..Now I have proper spacing from top. But, the tableview size is small..it is of the very size I have in my xib..and the tableview scrolls within that size only...

Comment: Does the `tableView` have enough space to expand?

Comment: Make the bottom constraint as >= 0 from the superView like I did in the screenshot attached.

Comment: There must be some issue with the constraints. Try in a separate project first.

Comment: actually I wanted the behaviour I got when I added the code  mentioned in the question...the issue with that was the tableview was not entirely scrolling to the bottom thereby not making the last cell visible and the tableview was overlapping the label above the tableview..

Comment: The solution I gave works perfectly at my end with `tableView` height increasing as expected.